# Unity object smooth rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to achieve this type of rotation of the object but with smooth movement. How can i do that?

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse1))
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(mainCamera.eulerAngles.x, mainCamera.eulerAngles.y, 0f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to do it with this one.

```
float turnTime = 50f;
Quaternion target = Quaternion.Euler(mainCamera.eulerAngles.x, mainCamera.eulerAngles.y, 0f);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, target, turnTime * Time.deltaTime);
```