# Smooth Turning C# unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have managed to go backwards and forwards with my kart in Unity. But when it comes to turning, it becomes a real challenge and I am unable to turn my vehicle smoothly with my a & d keys.

Please help!

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class KartController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private Rigidbody rb;
        // adding a speed variable
        public float speed = 3.0f;
        // adding a brake variable
        public float BrakeSpeed = 1.0f;
        // adding a rotation position variable
        
        // Start is called before
        void Start()
        {
            // refering to the game object component/class
            rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        }
    
        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            // adding movement for forward
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(speed * -2, 0, 0);
            }

            // adding movement for backward
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(speed * 2, 0, 0); 
            }
    
            // adding movement for rotation
            float rotation_speed = 10f;
    
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Horizontal"))
            {
                transform.Rotate(0.0f, -Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * rotation_speed, 0.0f);
            }

            Debug.Log(rotation_speed);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67316263/unity-object-smooth-rotation

Comment: It would be really useful to have an explanation of what happens when you try to rotate- is it jerky? Too fast? Too slow? Is it consistent both directions? What did you try changing to fix it and what did your changes do?

Comment: I would recommend using AddForce with rigidbodies, because that will give you that smooth feeling you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few different options and you are mixing a few things up.

Your Kart is a Rigidbody with a physics simulation. To move it forward or backwards you are setting the Karts velocity. If an object has a velocity in the physics simulation it will try to move because in the simulation the standard physics formula are solved. I.e. distance moved = velocity * time

For rotation the same concepts apply. There is the angular velocity of a rigidbody. If an object has angular velocity it tries to rotate accordingly.

With transform Rotate you are setting the rotation of the object directly. You are basically skipping the physics simulation. This is good if you want to for example reset your kart orientation and position at the start of the race but is less suited to control your Kart in the simulation.

You could directly set rb.angularVelocity similar how you set the Karts directional velocity.

Depending on the type of game and the realism you might want to look into controlling the acceleration instead of the velocity. Or even wheelcollider... (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/WheelColliderTutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code to select the car, I hope it can help you, thank you

```
       private float y;
      //vehicle control speed parameters
       private float speedOne = 0f; //Vehicle real-time speed
       private float speedMax = 120f; //The maximum speed of the vehicle
       private float speedMin = -20f; //The minimum speed of the vehicle (the maximum speed of reversing)
       private float speedUpA = 2f; //Vehicle acceleration acceleration (A key control)
       private float speedDownS = 4f; //Vehicle deceleration acceleration (S key control)
       private float speedTend = 0.5f; //Acceleration when no operation real-time speed tends to 0
       private float speedBack = 1f; //Vehicle reversing acceleration
      // Update is called once per frame
      void Update()
    {
        //mouse hide
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
       //Press the W key and the speed does not reach the maximum, then the speed increases
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && speedOne < speedMax)
       {
          speedOne = speedOne + Time.deltaTime * speedUpA;
       }
       //Press the S key and the speed does not reach zero, then the speed is reduced
       if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) && speedOne > 0f)
      {
         speedOne = speedOne - Time.deltaTime * speedDownS;
      }
     // No speed operation is performed and the speed is greater than the minimum speed, then the slow operation
      if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) && speedOne > 0f)
      {
         speedOne = speedOne - Time.deltaTime * speedTend;
      }
      if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) && speedOne < 0f)
      {
        speedOne = speedOne + Time.deltaTime * speedTend;
      }

      //When the S key is pressed and the speed does not reach the maximum reversing speed, and the vehicle is in a state where the vehicle can be reversed, the vehicle reverses
      if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) && speedOne > speedMin && speedOne<=0)
      {
        speedOne = speedOne - Time.deltaTime * speedBack;
      }

        /// press space, the car stops
      if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && speedOne != 0)
      {
        speedOne = Mathf.Lerp(speedOne, 0, 0.4f);
        if (speedOne < 5) speedOne = 0;
       }
      transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speedOne * Time.deltaTime);
     //Use A and D to control the left and right rotation of the object
       if(speedOne>1f||speedOne<-1f)
       {
           y = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * 60f * Time.deltaTime;
           transform.Rotate(0, y, 0);
       }
    
       /* if (transform.eulerAngles.z != 0)
       {
           transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.eulerAngles.x, t 
           ransform.eulerAngles.y, 0);
       }*/
     }
```